# Custom top menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to have a menu like the one in this demo http://yoko.elmastudio.de/, I mean the one with Category 1, sub category 1, sub category 2, .... Looking in the setting menu (into the admin dashboard) I can't find anything useful as there are only widgets that I can drag and drop in the 2nd or 3rd column but not in the top and using all the blog width.
I've done some Google and WP official website search for plug-ins but I didn't find what I was looking for...does anyboudy know how can I realize a top menu like the link posted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theme supports it and you are using WP 3.0 or above the custom menus can be created by clicking the "Menus" item under the "Appearance" menu.

WordPress custom menus allow you to create multiple menus and assign pages, categories, custom URL's, etc. as menu items.  You can then move them around using a drag and drop interface, allowing you to specify order and organize them hierarchical.

Once you have created the menus, you assign them to a particular "Theme Location" as defined in your theme.

Visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen for more information.

Comment: Unfortunally in my "theme localiton" I can find just the "my_menu" item (where "my_menu" is the name of the menu I've just created few seconds ago). This allow me to make my menu but this appare in the top of the page and it is not looking like the one I am trying to copy. I am quite sure that with my theme is possibile to make that menu because I am using the same theme.

Comment: Ok, I've found this awesome video wich is made specifically for what I was looking for and specifically for my theme. Great! http://vimeo.com/24772659